# load() a template file

Tags: ajax

I am developing a custom module which allows to bookmark nodes/taxonomy pages in ajax.

So far i can store in cookie via a custom module andsimple ajax code.
I am now struggling in refreshing some div in my page.
The "div" is actually a stand-alone file stored in my theme's template directory, whent trying to $.load it i get a 500 server error, must be colliding with the url-rewriting or simply the rights.

Is there a way to extract this file from the theme,
Store it in the module, call it from my theme's header.tpl.php,
And finaly, make it refresh when some jquery triggers ?

Comment: _must be colliding with the url-rewriting or simply the rights_ Any reason you can't just fix that? What do your error logs say?

Comment: Ok, now i can see more clearly the problem,
The error comes from the fact that the file i try to load,
Contains php logic, and drupal functions.
It starts to load fine but when it encounters something like that :
$chapitre = taxonomy_term_load($key);
It fails and returns 500 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i suceeded.

i just used jQuery.load to load the current page and load only the div i needed.